# getting error while installing flaskr in virtual environment

Tags: flask, deployment

This error appears while I run the command pip install -e . in virtual environment in the directory where pyproject.toml, MANIFEST.in and requirements.txt are there.
Installing build dependencies ... done
Checking if build backend supports build_editable ... done
Getting requirements to build editable ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build editable did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [14 lines of output]
error: Multiple top-level packages discovered in a flat-layout: ['flaskr', 'instance'].

```
  To avoid accidental inclusion of unwanted files or directories,
  setuptools will not proceed with this build.
  
  If you are trying to create a single distribution with multiple packages
  on purpose, you should not rely on automatic discovery.
  Instead, consider the following options:
  
  1. set up custom discovery (`find` directive with `include` or `exclude`)
  2. use a `src-layout`
  3. explicitly set `py_modules` or `packages` with a list of names
  
  To find more information, look for "package discovery" on setuptools docs.
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error